# Map with a lambda function

Tags: python, dictionary

```
c=map(lambda *x:x, range(3))
print(list(c))

c=map(lambda x:x, range(3))
print(list(c))
```

Can someone tell me how is the output different if we use variable positional args

```
[(0,), (1,), (2,)] #1st output

[0, 1, 2] #2nd output
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `map` or `lambda` per se, you are really just asking how variable positional arguments work. When you use `def func(*args):` then `args` will be a *tuple* of the objects passed by the caller of `func`, so `func(1,2,'foo')` will give you `args == (1, 2, 'foo')`, if you only pass a single argument, then you will have a singleton tuple: `func(1)` will give you `args == (1,)`

Comment: much appreciated..ty